# Need to fetch Oracle RAW in C# string datatype "as is"

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-6

Help me out, requirement is that I need the same value of Oracle RAW to be in C# as a string. I am able to save String as RAW value in oracle table, but while fetching it is giving 
exception "Object must implement IConvertible"

which I can understand that since RAW data type is not mapped to any primary data type so complier is giving this exception, But How can I achieve this?

I am using EF6 code first approach, in backend I am using Oracle 12C,

Below is the sample code,

```
 public partial class EF6TEST
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
   // [MaxLength(32)]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string NAME { get; set; }
}
 public class BE
{
    public string id;
    public string name;
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<BE> be;
        try
        {
            using (var context = new Model1())
            {
                #region insert
                context.EF6TEST.Add(new EF6TEST()
                {
                    ID = "96A8B17B17FB464B886146A28399E7E2",
                    NAME = "NewRAM"
                });
                #endregion
                context.SaveChanges();

                #region fetch
                be = (from t in context.EF6TEST
                      select new BE
                      {
                          id = t.ID,
                          name = t.NAME
                      }).ToList<BE>();


                #endregion                                       

            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception found");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Compilers don't give exceptions - exceptions occur at execution time, not compile-time. Please clarify *when* you're getting the error.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding it is runtime error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RAW datatype is [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT613) as:

> The RAW and LONG RAW datatypes are used for data that is not to be interpreted (not converted when moving data between different systems) by Oracle Database. These datatypes are intended for binary data or byte strings.

In other words, it's a better mapping for `byte[]` than `string`. Converting to a string requires an encoding to be applied.

I suggest you *try* mapping your column to `byte[]` instead, and then convert it to a string using an appropriate encoding within .NET. (e.g. `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)`.)

Comment: I tried converting Id as byte[] also and used                                            var be1 = (from t in context.EF6TEST
                         select t.ID).ToList();                                                            var be2 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(be1.FirstOrDefaul());   but that gives different set of string, Used encoding with Default, ASCII, Unicode but everytime diffrenet set of characters are coming as result.

Comment: @VSharma: Well what *is* the data? Where did it come from? Is it actually text data at all?

Comment: If you see code first I add one string "96A8B17B17FB464B886146A28399E7E2" in ID field that gets saved in oracle RAW data type column field. Next I try to fetch same value

Comment: @VSharma: But what *bytes* do you see coming back? Fundamentally, you shouldn't be saving it as a string either - I would advise using `byte[]` *everywhere* that you interact directly with `RAW`.

Comment: I got your answer @Jon. Pretty satisfied so making it as answers.

Answer (score 0):

In class C#

```
public class MyClass
{
    public byte[] Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In query select

```
SELECT 
  id      AS Id,  
  name    AS Name
  FROM my_table
WHERE id = :V_ID
```

The return of select convert the Id to this format

```
 var dto = new MyClassDto {
     Id = new Guid(myClass.Id),
     Name = myClass.Name
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this using Dapper. The Raw value came back as a byte[] array with 16 values. Each value in the array was the decimal value of each byte of the guid.  Here is code to convert to string:

```
public class MyObject
{        
    public byte[] Guid { get; set; }
}

myObject.Guid.Select(x => x.ToString("X")))
```